# sam local invoke function timeouts when connecting to dynamodb docker compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb, localhost, sam

I am trying to connect a local sam app (hello world example) to a dynamodb docker container running with docker compose. When I try to execute the lambda functions locally with python3 everything works perfect, I am able to write and delete data from tables, but when I try to invoke the same function with

`sam local invoke ReadTableFunction --event events/event_read.json --debug`

I get this timeout

```
Connect timeout on endpoint URL: \"http://localhost:8000/
```

I am able to list my tables with the aws cli at localhost

> ```
> aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
> ```
>
> {
> "TableNames": [
> "table_redirections"
> ] }

I somewhere read that when you refer to localhost inside a docker container you are referring to the actual localhost of the container, not the localhost from your PC, so I think that the problem might be something about connections.

This is my docker compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  dynamodb-local:
    command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"
    image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - "./docker/dynamodb:/home/dynamodblocal/data"
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
```

How can I make SAM local invoke function be able to talk or recognize the docker containers IP from my dockercompose dynamodb at localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some time of research I managed to make the connection with both of the containers.

I decided to set a static IP address to my dynamodb container to prevent having to update each time the IP address in the code.
First I ran the command `docker-compose up` with my file and after that I ran `docker network ls` to find my dockercompose NETWORK ID, then ran `docker network inspect 'MY_NETWORK_ID'` to find the current ipv4 address that the db container was using.

Now you shutdown your docker compose with `docker-compose down`

Once i had the IP address I had to modify a little bit my docker compose like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  dynamodb-local:
    command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"
    image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - "./docker/dynamodb:/home/dynamodblocal/data"
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
    hostname: dynamodb
    networks:
      dynamodbNetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.22.0.2
        aliases:
        - dynamodblocal


networks:
  dynamodbNetwork:
    name: dynamo_net
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.22.0.2/16"
```

What is happening here is that we are creating a custom subnet for the docker compose with a static IPv4.

Now we can do `docker-compose up`
and invoke our functions with our custom subnet included like this:

```
sam local invoke ReadTableFunction --event events/event_read.json --debug --docker-network dynamo_net
```

All solved